# What are the conditions on $f$ required to use $|\int f(x) dx| = \int |f(x)| dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

What are the conditions required to use $|\int f(x) dx| = \int |f(x)| dx$? or is it the triangle inequality only

Thank you.

Comment: so the function must be positive valued? @stein

Comment: If $f$ takes on negative values only, it's also true.

Comment: So is there a problem at 0?@kimchilover

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem at zero or with negative/positive values at all.

Comment: Actually the condition to "use it" is the condition itself. If it is not true then you cannot use it.

Comment: @drhab  Imean the conditions on F that allow me to do so

Comment: Then a better title would be: "Under what condition on $f$ do we have $|\int f(x)\;dx|=\int|f(x)|\;dx$?"

Comment: I have corrected it @drhab thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue as follows

1. Write the integral as an infinite sum (i.e. limit of finite sums)
2. For each finite sum use the usual triangle inequality
3. use the fact that $a_n\leq b_n$ implies $\lim_n a_n \leq \lim_n b_n$ where $a_n,b_n$ are the partial sums with the absolute values in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 3):

Set $f^+ = \max\{f,0\}$ and $f^- = \max\{-f, 0\}$. Both $f^+, f^- \ge 0$.

Then $f = f^+ - f^-$ and $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ so
$$\left|\int_{[a,b]} f^+ - \int_{[a,b]} f^-\right| = \left|\int_{[a,b]} f\right| = \int_{[a,b]} |f| = \int_{[a,b]} f^+ + \int_{[a,b]} f^-$$

Notice that $|a-b| = a+b$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$ so we conclude $\int_{[a,b]} f^+ = 0$ or $\int_{[a,b]} f^- = 0$.

In the first case $f^+ \equiv 0$ (a.e.) and in the second case $f^- \equiv 0$ (a.e.).

Hence $f \ge 0$ (a.e.) or $f \le 0$ (a.e.).